# How to sort a list in python to make lowercase precede uppercase?

Tags: python

Sorry this may be a naive question. But I am a newbie to python and this confuses me for a while.

I know how to treat all strings as lowercase by applying str.lower(), but I don't know how to intentionally put elements with lowercase letter as the first letter before uppercase ones.

For clarification:
Here is a example list: `[Bear, bear, Apple, apple]`

I want it to be: `[apple, Apple, bear, Bear]`

Comment: You can check for case with `islower()` and `isupper()`.

Comment: "put lowercase strings before uppercase ones"? please clarify.

Comment: Python's lexicographical sort (the default for strings) puts all capital letters before all lowercase letters.

Comment: Please show a sample of what the expected output is for your code, sample input, and the code that you have attempted.

Comment: What order would you want for... `[Bear, bear, beE, bAT]` ?

Comment: So it's sorted alphabetically, but lower case words would show up earlier in the list?

Comment: Using whole worlds as an example and in this case is useless/redundant. Start letters will do: [B, b, A, a]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can chain two sorts like this, since Python's sort is stable

```
>>> sorted(sorted(['Bear', 'bear', 'Apple', 'apple'], reverse=True), key=str.lower)
['apple', 'Apple', 'bear', 'Bear']
```

Or you can use a single sort, like this:

Python2:

```
>>> sorted(['Bear', 'bear', 'Apple', 'apple'], key=lambda x: (x.lower(), x.swapcase()))
['apple', 'Apple', 'bear', 'Bear']
```

Python3:

```
>>> sorted(['Bear', 'bear', 'Apple', 'apple'], key=lambda x: (x.casefold(), x.swapcase()))
['apple', 'Apple', 'bear', 'Bear']
```

Comment: Ooo ... `str.casefold`.  That's a nifty one.

Comment: Double sorting! Nice!  BTW, using whole worlds as an example and in this case was useless/redundant in the first place; start letters would do: [B, b, A, a] -> ['a', 'A', 'b', 'B']  Also, using `key=str.lower` or `key=str.upper` doesn't make any difference. But stupidly enough, one of them has to be used!

Answer (score 4):

```
In [95]: L = ['Bear', 'bear', 'Apple', 'apple']

In [96]: sorted(L, key=lambda s:(s.lower(), s[0].isupper()))
Out[96]: ['apple', 'Apple', 'bear', 'Bear']
```

Comment: Is this correct though?  What about `['aPple', 'apple']`?

Comment: @mgilson: not quite sure... but it seems to fit the examples

Answer (score 2):

Python's built-in sorting functions are stable, meaning that items will only move around on subsequent sorts if the new sorting key requires it. This means that you can simply sort multiple times, with a different key.

```
>>> my_list = ['Bear', 'bear', 'Apple', 'apple']
>>> my_list = sorted(my_list, key=str.istitle)
>>> my_list
['bear', 'apple', 'Bear', 'Apple']
>>> my_list = sorted(my_list, key=str.lower)
>>> my_list
['apple', 'Apple', 'bear', 'Bear']
```