# How to sort a list to get all lowercase alphabet words before uppercase?

Tags: python, sorting

I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161059/how-to-sort-a-list-in-python-to-make-lowercase-precede-uppercase) and tried various probabilities to get the desired output

```
sorted(['aa', 'bb', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA'])
['AA', 'BB', '_dd', 'aa', 'bb']

sorted(['aa', 'bb', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA'], reverse=True)
['bb', 'aa', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA']

sorted(['aa', 'bb', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA'], key=str.lower)
['_dd', 'aa', 'AA', 'bb', 'BB']

sorted(['aa', 'bb', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA'], reverse=True, key=str.lower)
['bb', 'BB', 'aa', 'AA', '_dd']

sorted(sorted(['aa', 'bb', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA'], reverse=False), key=str.lower)
['_dd', 'AA', 'aa', 'BB', 'bb']

sorted(sorted(['aa', 'bb', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA'], reverse=True), key=str.lower)
['_dd', 'aa', 'AA', 'bb', 'BB']

sorted(sorted(['aa', 'bb', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA'], reverse=True), key=lambda x: (x.lower(), x.swapcase()))
['_dd', 'aa', 'AA', 'bb', 'BB']

sorted(['aa', 'bb', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA'], key=str.istitle)
['aa', 'bb', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA']

sorted(['aa', 'bb', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA'], reverse=True, key=str.istitle)
['aa', 'bb', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA']

sorted(['aa', 'bb', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA'], reverse=False, key=str.istitle)
['aa', 'bb', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA']

sorted(sorted(['aa', 'bb', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA']), key=str.istitle)
['AA', 'BB', '_dd', 'aa', 'bb']

sorted(sorted(['aa', 'bb', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA'], reverse=True), key=str.istitle)
['bb', 'aa', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA']
```

But I need the output to be in this order

```
['_dd', 'aa', 'bb', 'AA', 'BB']
```

Comment: Perhaps: `key=lambda s: (s.isalpha(), s.swapcase()))`

Comment: Yes, it worked! `sorted(sorted(['aa', 'bb', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA']), key=lambda s: (s.isalpha(), s.swapcase()))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sorted(['aa', 'bb', '_dd', 'BB', 'AA'], key=lambda s: (s.upper() == s, s))
```

Tuples are sorted by its first item before the second, and bools are sorted as False before true, so the `s.upper() == s` will sort all non-uppercase ones before the others.

Note that, if your purpose is language-oriented sorting, you should probably look into using `key=functools.cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll)` or similar instead.